# What is the logical error in the for loop?

Tags: python

This is the question:

> Use the debugging tool, IDLE Debugger to correct a logical error in a
>   Python program. The program should generate a pattern of rows of
>   asterisks in even columns and dollars in odd columns, where the number
>   of row and column is input by the user. The expected output is:
>
> [image: asterickdollar]

So where the error at? I couldnt figure it out the logical error.
The code is:

```
row = col = int(input("Enter number of row and column: "))
for row in range(row):
    for col in range(col):
        if row % 2 == 0 and col % 2 == 1:
            print('*', end='')
        elif row % 2 == 1 and col % 2 == 0:
            print('$', end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')

    print()
```

[For the above code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Bxl.png)

Comment: Did you try using the suggested debugger to see where things start going wrong?

Comment: @user2357112 Ya. But i still dont understand. I tried to edit and it does not   show the expected output

Comment: What is wrong with your output? please show us your output.

Comment: amotsg's answer is write. you should change the name of the variable of the inner loop to something else. for example like this: `for col_var in range(col):`

Comment: @Navid777 I got it! Appreciate it for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the number the user inputs in a different variable than the ones you use to iterate.
This worked:

```
num = int(input("Enter number of row and column: "))
for row in range(num):
    for col in range(num):
        if row % 2 == 0 and col % 2 == 1:
            print('*', end='')
        elif row % 2 == 1 and col % 2 == 0:
            print('$', end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')

    print()
```

Comment: I understood ! Appreciate it. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You use col and row both for the input and for the variables of the loop step.

As `range` (and your algorithm) is zero based, after the first run of the inner `for`, the value of `col` will be smaller by one from the original desired input. And so on.

This will work:

```
rows = columns = int(input("Enter number of row and column: "))
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(columns):
        if row % 2 == 0 and col % 2 == 1:
        print('*', end='')
    elif row % 2 == 1 and col % 2 == 0:
        print('$', end='')
    else:
        print(' ', end='')

print()
```

In python, loop variables are defined in the scope where the loop run and not in the inner scope of the loop. So they both 'run over' variables previously defined and stay defined after the loop ends.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is an error, after every run of the inner loop it, on every iteration of the outer, it will start from a smaller range. As the end value of col will always be smaller by one.

Comment: Appreciate for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rules: Too many logical conditions makes for difficult debugging and too many divisions makes for slow code (your doing a division operation up to 4 times per loop!) and your `for` loops are nested so you've squared the number of iterations required.

Set out as much of your logic as possible before your loop starts, it simplifies things.

```
rows = cols = int(input("Enter number of row and column: "))
isAsterix = True
extraColumns =  cols % 2  # 1 if odd; 0 otherwise
numDoubleColumns = int(cols / 2)  # rounds down
for _ in range(rows):
    if isAsterix:
        bigCol = ' *'  # will  be multiplied up to column full width
        pad = ' ' # used if odd number of columns
    else:
        bigCol = '$ '  # will  be multiplied up to column full width
        pad = '$'  # used if odd number of columns

    # yes you can multiply and add strings together...
    print(bigCol*numDoubleColumns + pad*extraColumns)
    isAsterix = not isAsterix  # print the other symbol next time
```

I appreciate for this example the speed gains will be negligible, but it's still good practice to keep in mind where `for` loops can be removed. And it's definitely good to simplify your `if` statements.